# Opening a URL in new tabs generates 404 when URL isn't complete

Tags: javascript, url

I want to open a new tab when a user clicks on a link. The link is user generated and when users enter a url like www.google.com the tab doesn't work as expected. This is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujbqktc6/) to show the problem and this is the code:

```
<a href="javascript: var a = window.open('www.google.com')">open new tab</a>
```

How can I fix this? Telling users to enter a well-formed URL is not an option.

Comment: Because absolute URLs start with `http://`, `https://`, `ftp:`...

Comment: Can you show us in the HTML/js how you have the user entering a URL?

Comment: @JoeL: it's a web app where users upload a spreadsheet into a sales software. See my profile to look at the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't Forget The Protocol**

The `window.open()` function expects the appropriate protocol to be present when requesting the URL (i.e. `http://`, `ftp://`, `https://`, etc.), so you'll need to ensure that you include this to work properly :

```
window.open('http://www.google.com');
```

**Manually Prepending The Protocol**

If you need to explicitly omit the protocol for whatever reason, you could consider writing a function to handle opening your window for you :

```
function openWindowAndPrependProtocol(url){
    if(/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)){
        // If it doesn't start with http:// or https://, then append it
        return window.open('http://' + url);
    }
}
```

which would change your code to use :

```
var a = openWindowAndPrependProtocol('www.google.com');
```

**Note**

According to Mozilla, they [generally don't recommend using links in this manner to open new windows via `window.open()` if at all possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Avoid_resorting_to_window.open.28.29), as it can bring about some usability concerns. Their [best practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Best_practices) recommends using an external function similar to the second approach to handle opening the window.

Comment: Problem is that users who aren't programmers don't understand this. Needs to work the way typical users think.

Comment: If that is the case, you may want to make a function that will encapsulate this logic for you and append the protocol if it doesn't exist as mentioned in my update above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a protocol automatically to an URL, which a user of your page provided, you can do this with the following function:

JavaScript *(needs be added somewhere on your page)*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openURL(url) {
        var allowedProtocols = ["http://", "https://", "ftp://", "ftps://"];
        var hasPrefix = false;

        for(var i = 0; i < allowedProtocols.length; i++) {
            if(url.substring(0, allowedProtocols[i].length) === allowedProtocols[i]) {
                hasPrefix = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!hasPrefix) {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }

        window.open(url);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="openURL('www.google.com')">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', 'Google', 'width=800,height=800')">
```

It opens in a new tab and 800×800 are the dimensions of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a protocol like `http://` or `https://`

```
<a href="javascript: var a = window.open('http://google.com')">open new tab</a>`
```

Comment: you were quicker :)

Comment: Problem is that users who aren't programmer don't understand this. Needs to work the way typical users think.